# WEKA: Classify instances with a deserialized model

Tags: java, weka

I used Weka Explorer:

- Loaded the arff file
- Applied StringToWordVector filter
- Selected IBk as the best classifier
- Generated/Saved my_model.model binary

In my Java code I deserialize the model:

```
    URL curl = ClassUtility.findClasspathResource( "models/my_model.model" );
    final Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read( curl.openConnection().getInputStream() );
```

Now, I have the classifier BUT I need somehow the information on the filter. Where I am getting is: how do I prepare an instance to be classified by my deserialized model (how do I apply the filter before classification) - (The raw instance that I have to classify has a field text with tokens in it. The filter was supposed to transform that into a list of new attributes)

I even tried to use a `FilteredClassifier` where I set the classifier to the deserialized on and the filter to a manually created instance of `StringToWordVector`

```
    final StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
    filter.setOptions(new String[]{"-C", "-P x_", "-L"});
    FilteredClassifier fcls = new FilteredClassifier();
    fcls.setFilter(filter);
    fcls.setClassifier(cls);
```

The above does not work either. It throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No output instance format defined
```

What I am trying to avoid is doing the training in the Java code. It can be very slow and the prospect is that I might have multiple classifiers to train (different algorithms as well) and I want my app to start fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your model doesn't know anything about what the filter did to the data. The `StringToWordVector` filter changes the data, but depending on the input (training) data. A model trained on this transformed data set will only work on data that underwent the **exact same transformation**. To guarantee this, the filter needs to be part of your model.

Using a `FilteredClassifier` is the correct idea, but you have to use it from the beginning:

- Load the ARFF file
- Select `FilteredClassifier` as classifier
- Select `StringToWordVector` as filter for it
- Select `IBk` as classifier for the `FilteredClassifier`
- Generate/Save the model to my_model.binary

The trained and serialized model will then also contain the intialized filter, including the information on how to transform data.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the same filter to your testing data as the one used on training data. I describe the procedure analytically. In your case you just need to follow steps after the loading of your serialized classifier.

- Create your training file (e.g training.arff)
- Create Instances from training file. `Instances trainingData = ..`
- Use **StringToWordVector** to transform your string attributes to number representation:

*sample code:*

```
    StringToWordVector() filter = new StringToWordVector(); 
    filter.setWordsToKeep(1000000);
    if(useIdf){
        filter.setIDFTransform(true);
    }
    filter.setTFTransform(true);
    filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
    filter.setOutputWordCounts(true);
    filter.setMinTermFreq(minTermFreq);
    filter.setNormalizeDocLength(new SelectedTag(StringToWordVector.FILTER_NORMALIZE_ALL,StringToWordVector.TAGS_FILTER));
    NGramTokenizer t = new NGramTokenizer();
    t.setNGramMaxSize(maxGrams);
    t.setNGramMinSize(minGrams);    
    filter.setTokenizer(t);  
    WordsFromFile stopwords = new WordsFromFile();
    stopwords.setStopwords(new File("data/stopwords/stopwords.txt"));
    filter.setStopwordsHandler(stopwords);
    if (useStemmer){
        Stemmer s = new /*Iterated*/LovinsStemmer();
        filter.setStemmer(s);
    }
    filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);
```

- Apply the filter to trainingData: `trainingData = Filter.useFilter(trainingData, filter);`
- Select a classifier to create your model

*sample code for LibLinear classifier*

```
        Classifier cls = null;
        LibLINEAR liblinear = new LibLINEAR();
        liblinear.setSVMType(new SelectedTag(0, LibLINEAR.TAGS_SVMTYPE));
        liblinear.setProbabilityEstimates(true);
        // liblinear.setBias(1); // default value
        cls = liblinear;
        cls.buildClassifier(trainingData);
```

- Save model

*sample code*

```
    System.out.println("Saving the model...");
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+"mymodel.model"));
    oos.writeObject(cls);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
```

- Create a testing file (e.g testing.arff)
- Create Instances from training file: `Instances testingData=...`
- Load classifier

*sample code*

```
Classifier myCls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(path+"mymodel.model");
```

- **Use the same StringToWordVector filter as above or create a new one for testingData, but remember to use the trainingData for this command:`filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);`** *This will keep the format of training set and will not add words that are not in training set.*
- Apply the filter to testingData: `testingData = Filter.useFilter(testingData, filter);`
- Classify!

*sample code*

```
 for (int j = 0; j < testingData.numInstances(); j++) {
    double res = myCls.classifyInstance(testingData.get(j));
 }
```